# Given the Conditions, why $ f \equiv 1 $?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function on $ \mathbb{C}$ such that

- $f(0)=1$
- $f'(0)=0$
- $0 < |f(z)|\leqslant e ^{|z|} \  \text{ for every }   z \in  \mathbb{C}$

Then $ f \equiv 1$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

$f$ is an entire zero-free function, so we can write $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g$. $g$ is determined up to multiples of $2\pi i$, since $f(0) = 1$, let's pick the choice with $g(0) = 0$.

The condition $f'(0) = 0$ translates into $g'(0) = 0$, since $f'(0) = e^{g(0)}g'(0)$.

The condition $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant e^{\lvert z\rvert}$ translates into $\operatorname{Re} g(z) \leqslant \lvert z\rvert$.

So $\operatorname{Re} g$ is an entire harmonic function that grows at most as fast as $\lvert z\rvert$. Using the Poisson integral, we deduce that $\operatorname{Re} g$ is a linear polynomial (or constant). But $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$, hence $\operatorname{Re} g \equiv 0$.

So $g$ is an entire function with constant real part, so constant, hence $g\equiv 0$ and $f \equiv 1$.

Comment: We can deduce a similar more general result: If $f$ is an entire function of exponential type, then $f$ has the form $f=p e^{az}$ for some polynomial $p$ and a constant $a$. The proof for this has the same ideas as the proof of Daniel Fischer.

In your case we have $p=1$, since $f$ has no zeros at all, and from the fact $f'(0)=0$ we deduce $a=0$.